# Send File to .Net API with powershell

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

In postman, sending the file to the API, works perfectly.

[image]

If I try to replicate the same, but in powershell it doesnt work. Everything seems fine, but the file doesnt arrive to the code at C#.Net.

This property, when sending it with postman, is defined, but when sending it with powershell its null.

[image]

The code of powershell, is the "export" of the call in postman auto-generated.

```
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer authrization.token.jwt")

$multipartContent = [System.Net.Http.MultipartFormDataContent]::new()
$multipartFile = '/C:/Users/user-name/Downloads/send-file.json'
$FileStream = [System.IO.FileStream]::new($multipartFile, [System.IO.FileMode]::Open)
$fileHeader = [System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue]::new("form-data")
$fileHeader.Name = "File"
$fileHeader.FileName = "/C:/Users/user-name/Downloads/send-file.json"
$fileContent = [System.Net.Http.StreamContent]::new($FileStream)
$fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = $fileHeader
$multipartContent.Add($fileContent)

$stringHeader = [System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue]::new("form-data")
$stringHeader.Name = "Name"
$stringContent = [System.Net.Http.StringContent]::new("oee")
$stringContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = $stringHeader
$multipartContent.Add($stringContent)

$body = $multipartContent

$response = Invoke-RestMethod 'http://localhost:7071/sendfile' -Method 'POST' -Headers $headers -Body $body
$response | ConvertTo-Json
```

Comment: Did you remember to replace `authrization.token.jwt` with an actual valid bearer token?

Comment: What is in `$response`?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Of course I did. This is just to not share the token with you.

Comment: @Crowcoder There is no response, the Back end returns a 500. 

The problem is that as in the screenshot provided, the request.form.Files is null in the powershell call, but it's fullfiled in the postman call